# Proper way of overriding generic methods in Java

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, raw-types

Consider the following code:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Person {}
class OtherPerson {}
class SomeDummyClass {}

interface A {
    <E>List<E> foo();
}

class B implements A {
    @Override
    public List<Object> foo() {
        return Arrays.asList(Integer.valueOf(3), new Person(), new OtherPerson());
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        List<SomeDummyClass> someDummyClasses = a.foo();

        System.out.println(someDummyClasses.get(0)); // prints 3
    }
}
```

I'm confused why we can override the `foo()` method without any compile time errors. This particularly became less intuitive to reason about when I wrote `List<SomeDummyClass> someDummyClasses = a.foo();` and this is perfectly valid (no compile time error).

A real time example of this case is with `mybatis-3`.

- `A` mimics [`ResultHandler`](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/executor/resultset/ResultSetHandler.java)
- `B` mimics [`DefaultResultSetHandler`](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/executor/resultset/DefaultResultSetHandler.java) (This class is not package private - which I expected it should have been)
- `foo()` mimics [`handleResultSets`](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/executor/resultset/DefaultResultSetHandler.java#L181)

### Questions

- I understand that  why is this statement: `List<SomeDummyClass> someDummyClasses = a.foo();` not giving any compile time error. But at runtime, I thought it should have given a `ClassCastException`. What's actuall happening here?
- When I do `System.out.println(someDummyClasses.get(0));` I get a `ClassCastException`. Why is this so?
- Is there a better way to re-write these so that the code becomes less fragile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm confused why we can override the foo() method with any compile
>   time errros.

Yes but you have a compilation warning since the return type in the overrided method `List<Object>` is more specific that `List<E>` in the interface method :

> Unchecked overriding: return type requires unchecked conversion. Found
>   `java.util.List<java.lang.Object>`, required `java.util.List<E>`.

To not handle this kind of warning may lead to an inconsistent use of the generics.  And there you have a very good example.

About :

> This particularly became less intuitive to reason about when I wrote
>   List someDummyClasses = a.foo(); and this is perfectly
>   valid (no compile time error).

And why would you get a compilation error ?

Here you declare `a` as a `A` :

```
A a = new B();
```

So here :

```
List<SomeDummyClass> someDummyClasses = a.foo();
```

at compile time, `foo()` refers to the `<E> List<E> foo()` method declared in the interface and a method scoped generic with `E` that is not bounded (so is `Object`) is designed to adapt the declared return type to the target : here that is the type of the variable declared by the client of the method to assign the method return.

Change your declaration to :

```
B b = new B();  
List<SomeDummyClass> someDummyClasses = b.foo();
```

And the compilation would not even pass.

Note that your issue is not specific to overriding method. 
Declare a method (that also produces a warning about unchecked cast) :

```
public static <T> List<T> getListOfAny(){
    return (List<T>) new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

And you could use it in the same inconsistent way :

```
 List<String> listOfAny = getListOfAny();
```

The moral of this story : **don't consider unchecked conversions warnings produced by the compiler like cosmetics/details but handle them correctly and you could benefit as much as possible from the compilation check brought by generics.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I indeed unconsciously ignored the compiler warning. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You are welcome. For the story, some days ago impossible to understand a weird behavior of the compiler. In fact, that was caused by an unchecked conversion far enough of the current weird code. I will finish by increasing the severity level to error  of the unckecked conversion warning in my IDE :)

Answer (score 1):

> But at runtime, I thought it should have given a ClassCastException. What's actually happening here?

Remember that generics in Java are purely a compile-time thing. When your code is compiled, the compiler removes all the generic parameters, and adds casts where necessary. Your code at runtime looks like this:

```
interface A {
    List foo();
}

class B implements A {
    @Override
    public List foo() {
        return Arrays.asList(Integer.valueOf(3), new Person(), new OtherPerson());
    }
}

// ...

List someDummyClasses = a.foo();

System.out.println(someDummyClasses.get(0));
```

Look! Nothing is wrong here. There are no casts, let alone `ClassCastException`s.

There *would* be an `ClassCastException` if you did this:

```
SomeDummyClass obj = someDummyClasses.get(0);
```

Because the above code will become this at runtime:

```
SomeDummyClass obj = (SomeDummyClass)someDummyClasses.get(0);
```

> When I do System.out.println(someDummyClasses.get(0)); I get a `ClassCastException`. Why is this so?

[No it does not](https://ideone.com/bRsAjl).

> Is there a better way to re-write these so that the code becomes less fragile?

(Note that I don't know much about mybatis)

I think what you should do here is to make `A` a generic interface:

```
interface A<T> {
    List<T> foo();
}
```

And make `B implements A<Object>`. This way, at least it's more type-safe.

Comment: +1 for how will it look after compilation. The link [https://ideone.com/bRsAjl](https://ideone.com/bRsAjl) is not working. Can you please update it? I agree that `A<T>` will make more sense, and I'd have gone with this option if I was writing the library. I wonder why mybatis is not doing this (may be because it can end up with the interface parameterized over many types)

Comment: @LavishKothari That's weird. The link is still working for me. Try this one: https://repl.it/repls/FormalReadyProjector

Answer (score 0):

1st) The signature of A#foo is return a `<E> List<E>` that will return a list of the type being captured as E on asssignment, `List<X> = new A().foo()` (if A was a concrete class) compiles since it captures the type, while `List<X> = new B().foo()` return a `List<Object>` and cannot be assigned.

2nd) You get a ClassCastException since you assigned Integers, and Strings to a List

3rd) Your interface could have like `<E extends SummyDummyClass> List<E> foo();` turning the declaration on B class invalid and so on, also you will need less casts since you know in advance the type of the superclass of `E`

Comment: I assumed hes casting